# Hover on object entries triggers unnecessary reactivity in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have an object that I loop over with an each block. When I hover, I temporarily change a property on the actual object entry and use it to assign a class. This works fine, but it also causes other reactivity to be triggered unnecessarily often.

```html
<script>
    let things = [
        { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
        { id: 2, name: 'banana' },
        { id: 3, name: 'carrot' },
        { id: 4, name: 'doughnut' },
        { id: 5, name: 'egg' },
    ];
    
    function makePretty(somethings) {
        const prettyThings = somethings.map(thing => thing.name).join(' ');
        console.log(prettyThings);
        return prettyThings;
    }
    
    $: prettyThings = makePretty(things)
</script>

<ul>
{#each things as thing (thing.id)}
    <li 
            class:hover={thing.hover}
            on:mouseenter={() => (thing.hover = true)}
            on:mouseleave={() => (thing.hover = false)}
    >
        {thing.name}
    </li>
{/each}
</ul>

<style>
    .hover {
        background-color: cyan;
    }
</style>
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/c658cccd0bc2471a8f9c4758387340c5?version=3.48.0
n the console, you can see how often the reactivity on the prettyThings is triggered when you move over the list with your mouse.

I do realise that this is expected behaviour, as the 'things'-object is effectively changed on every mouseenter and mouseleave. And thus the prettyThings is called every time.

What would be an ideomatic way to apply a hover to a 'row' from an array of objects, without changing the object itself? In doing so, the object should still be live modifiable by other operations (e.g. add, delete, ...).

Comment: Why do you need that as part of the data? Usually things related to hover are about styling and can be done entirely in CSS.

Comment: I considered 'hovered' the be a kind of state, like 'selected', 'being edited', 'in the process of being deleted', ... and it seems convenient to have these 'row states' being aware of each other. E.g.: don't do the hover thing when the row is being edited. I know you can do many things with css, but that makes the logic quite spread out.

Comment: "hover" is the wrong domain, describe why it's hovered and map to it (`thing.hasPriority`, `thing.isNewItem`, ...).

Comment: I don't think I understand. Wouldn't this also change the 'thing', triggering the same surplus reactivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, would be to split the rendering into a separate component.

```html
<script>
    export let thing;
</script>

<li class:hover={thing.hover}
    on:mouseenter={() => (thing.hover = true)}
    on:mouseleave={() => (thing.hover = false)} >
    {thing.name}
</li>

<style>
    .hover {
        background-color: cyan;
    }
</style>
```

```html
{#each things as thing (thing.id)}
    <ItemDisplay {thing} />
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/026378e80bbf4f93b40f093ba37bc151?version=3.48.0)

Maybe there are better approaches, though.

Comment: Oh, this is very much like what I had hoped for. The simpler the better.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You could store the "Row Hovered" in a separate variable, then apply the style based on "HoveredRowId === thing.id"

```
<script>
    let things = [
        { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
        { id: 2, name: 'banana' },
        { id: 3, name: 'carrot' },
        { id: 4, name: 'doughnut' },
        { id: 5, name: 'egg' },
    ];
    
    let hoveredId = 0;
    
    function makePretty(somethings) {
        const prettyThings = somethings.map(thing => thing.name).join(' ');
        console.log(prettyThings);
        return prettyThings;
    }
    
    $: prettyThings = makePretty(things)
</script>

<ul>
{#each things as thing (thing.id)}
    <li 
            class:hover={thing.id === hoveredId}
            on:mouseenter={() => (hoveredId = thing.id)}
            on:mouseleave={() => (hoveredId = 0)}
    >
        {thing.name}
    </li>
{/each}
</ul>
<p>
    Hovered ID: {hoveredId}
</p>

<style>
    .hover {
        background-color: cyan;
    }
</style>
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/e157abc957874228983c9eafb2246aa3?version=3.48.0

Comment: As I mentioned in a reply above, I want the hovering to be a state on the row, so that other states (selected, being edited, pending delete, ...) will also know about it. By handling certain states only in css, the logic is quickly smeared out.

Comment: You could store the 'hoveredId' in a separate variable: https://svelte.dev/repl/e157abc957874228983c9eafb2246aa3?version=3.48.0

Comment: I like it, very clean and clear.